# Skip Optional Parameters When Calling Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

This seems like something that should be simple but I have not been able to get it working (yet).

I have a simple controller action defined like...

```
[Route("api/test/test1/{value1?}/{value2?}")]
public string Get(int? value1 = null, int? value2 = null)
{
}
```

I would like to call this action and specify a value for the value2 parameter but not the value1 parameter.

I can do this by using the URI...

```
/api/test/test1/?value2=1
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like...

```
/api/test/test1//1 /* Notice the double slash */
```

When I do this, the parameter value1 is assigned a value of 1 and the parameter value2 is assigned a value of null.  In this case, I would like to have the parameter value1 be assigned a value of null and the parameter value2 be assigned a value of 1.

Is this something that is even possible?  If so, how can I get it to work?

Comment: Did you try have multiple routes? Say one of them has value1 optional and value2 mandatory?

Comment: I tried adding another route as suggested.  However, using the example I provided, the value still gets assigned to the first parameter.